# In Sublime Text, when I use two column layout, how to open files from file manager in the first column only?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I generally use the two column view in Sublime Text, the first column as the primary column and the second one as an auxiliary one for I/O purposes. So I have the second column to be very small. But when I want to open a file via the file manager, it always opens in the second column. So what should I do to always make the files open in the first column?

Comment: Files should open on the column you're currently focused in.

Comment: No @sergioFC , it is not so, I have verified it. It always seems to open in the second column.

Comment: For me if I focus on the file of a column, and then double click a file in the sidebar, or open a file using menu File>Open, the file will open in the column I was focused in. Do you mean that when you say `open a file via the file manager`?. I'm using sublime text 3 3083 in linux mint.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it is obvious but I don't understand what the file manager is. Could you please post a screenshot of the file manager, or a gif showing your problem?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I use Nautilus, the default Ubuntu file manager (I am using the 14.04 version)

Comment: For me they open in the column that I was last focused in. I don't know how to solve this but if you want you can use drag and drop, and drop them in the column you want. This are gifs when I open files in two column layout using [file-manager](http://postimg.org/image/vb913jo99/), or using [drag and drop](http://postimg.org/image/7yhgrndjz/). If I understand you well that first doesn't happen for you.

Comment: I have been using drag and drop . Thanks for the effort anyway @sergioFC :)